# UITableViewController Sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to recreate the buggy CNContactPickerViewController made by Apple so I have an array of data `[CNContact]` which i need to display neatly in a UITableView. It all works great until i try to add sections based on the first letter of the contacts' last names to that table. The only solution i found is to iterate through the `[CNContact]` array and manually group every contact into a dictionary, based on their initials resulting in a `[String:[CNContact]]`. Is there a better way to do this?

The end result can be viewed in the screenshot below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will sort your contacts by last name. Might be overkill, as you want them grouped only by the first letter of the last name, whereas this will sort using the whole name.

```
  var contacts :[CNContact] = [CNContact]();
  // fill your contacts here
    contacts.sortInPlace { (contact1, contact2) -> Bool in
        contact1.familyName.compare(contact2.familyName) == .OrderedAscending
    }
```

Not sure if you need the original ordering. If you want the original array, do create copy of the old one, and do sort in place for the copy.